# Leak Detection on Natural Gas Line

Tags: gas, testing

Has anyone figured out a better method the locate a leak other than a Gas Pressure test gauge and Leak Detector Spray?

Answer (score 2):

1. Bottle of soapy water - pretty much what "leak detector spray" probably is.
2. Call the gas company. I have always found them **very** happy to help
   sort these things out before the building blows up and makes bad
   press for them. I suppose your gas company might vary, but probably not.

Comment: +1 while the IR camera in @JimmyFixIt's answer is really cool and I want one, soapy water is available in every household, making this a better answer IMO.

Answer (score 0):

Infra-red cameras, or what are sometimes called [thermal imaging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermography) devices, are great at finding methane and are much cheaper now (as low as like $200) than they were even just a few years ago:

[image]

There is even a [hack for your smartphone](https://hackaday.io/project/9832-kapula-the-thermal-smartphone)!